# Keep track of pypi dependencies - who is using my packages

Tags: python, dependencies, pypi

Is there anyway through either pip or PyPi to identify which projects (published on Pypi) might be using my packages (also published on PyPi)  - I would like to identify the user base for each package and possible attempt to actively engage with them.

Thanks in advance for any answers - even if what I am trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: If a project is not open-source, then I don't see how anyone could know. I'm not aware of any methods, but a naïve approach could be to search through all projects and scan their requirements.txt file of some sort. E.g. on Github, then perhaps you could use their [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to read a lot of repos, but I haven't used it and I don't know about the limitations.

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger that is what I suspected - I would imagine that most  projects have a requirements.txt file though. I don't know that github and pypi apis are like.

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger - I am only talking about projects of mine published on pypi - so yes- Open source. I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really possible. There is no easily accessible public dataset that lets you produce a dependency graph.

At most you could scan *all* publicly available packages to parse their dependencies, but even then those dependencies are generated by running the `setup.py` script, so the dependencies can be set dynamically. It is quite common to adjust the dependencies based on the Python version (installing a backport of a standard-library dependency on older Python versions, for example). People [have done this before](https://ogirardot.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/state-of-the-pythonpypi-dependency-graph/) but this is not an easy, lightweight task.

Note that even then, you'll only find publicly declared dependencies. Any dependencies declared by private packages, not published to PyPI or another public repository, can't be accounted for.

Comment: Peters - I thought that  might be the case. Even though it is possible to dynamically set the requirements within the setup.py - that information (I have done that myself) - I would have thought that those dependencies are stored in the Wheel - and therefore potentially available through pypi - clearly not though.
I will just have to be very careful with breaking changes.