# Finding reverse dependencies of a package on PyPI

Tags: python, pypi

I would like to find which packages on PyPI depend on a specific package. This is easy to do on package indexes for other languages. For example:

- [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) has "reverse depends" and "reverse imports" sections
- [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) has an entire "Reverse dependencies" page

Is this possible on PyPI?

Answer (score 4):

Found one possible answer. Wheelodex has a reverse dependencies index. For example, for setuptools:

- https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/setuptools/rdepends/

Answer (score 2):

Another place to look: if this is a GitHub project, check out its 'Used By' section:

[image]

For example: https://github.com/pksol/mock_autogen -> https://github.com/pksol/mock_autogen/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS00OTA5NDgxNTQ%3D

Answer (score 1):

PyPI does not track dependencies in any way. Dependencies are normally resolved by the installer (e.g. `pip`) dynamically by actually retrieving the packages.

Some third parties do attempt to collect this information, such as `libraries.io` which provides a "used by" summary. For projects mutually available on GitHub.com, GitHub may also provide information on a project's dependents.

A big difference between PyPI repository packages and, say, CRAN is that packages are not required to explicitly declare their dependencies as package metadata, which would make reverse-lookups trivial. Unfortunately, due to the method/flexibility PyPI packages have in declaring dependencies, this is not possible/practical for PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831598/3800552) suggests that it's not really possible, due to the fact that it's possible to add dependencies dynamically. Any results you would get would be partial.